# Getting react native and neo4j to work together

Tags: node.js, neo4j, react-native

Has anyone done this successfully and have a working code base? specifically when I try to use a neo4j driver it starts complaining that a bunch of really basic modules can't be found (assert, http, buffer, net etc). I've tried node-neo4j and neo4j-driver.

I try to install these modules one by one but that doesn't seem right.

Note that this is specific to react-native, if I use normal react on the front end and nodejs on the back end it seems to work fine

I took out almost everything out of my code to isolate the problem.

**Working:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  BackAndroid,
  Navigator,
  ToolbarAndroid,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

class AwesomeProject extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>HI</Text>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

**Not working:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  BackAndroid,
  Navigator,
  ToolbarAndroid,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert
} from 'react-native';

var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost", neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));

var session = driver.session();

class AwesomeProject extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>HI</Text>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

[image: Error]

Comment: I used react native's fetch and neo4j's http end point and it worked, but I don't know why none of the drivers worked

Answer (score 0):

`npm install net` will resolve that dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished in the following way:

1. Run `npm install -g browserify`
2. Navigate to the route folder of your project and create a new file called `neo4j-in.js` containing the following lines:

   ```
    var neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");
    module.exports = neo4j
   ```
3. Run `browserify neo4j-in.js -o neo4j.js`
4. Open the new `neo4j.js` file in a text editor and search for all instances of the word `require` (even functions) and replace every single one with `reqq`.
5. Add a new line to the very top of the script which says `var neo4j;`
6. Search for the line `module.exports = neo4j;` (which will be near the bottom of the script) and move it to a new line at the very bottom of the script outside of all functions.
7. Save the file as `neo4j.js` and move it into your `node_modules` folder alongside all of your other packages.
8. Change the line `var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;` to `var neo4j = require('neo4j')`

We are receiving this error because React Native does not contain the Core Node JS Modules required by the Javascript neo4j-driver, but we can get around this by creating a standalone Javascript file which contains the polyfill for the neo4j-driver module. This can be done for other packages as well which also rely upon Core Node JS Modules. Here is a thorough explanation if you would like more information. https://hackernoon.com/using-core-node-js-modules-in-react-native-apps-64acd4d07140